# In Flask how can I redirect to a template and show a message after returning send_file in a view?

Tags: python, flask

I'm diving into Flask for the first time and I'm running into a little problem. I have a page with a form and a bunch of checkboxes. When submitting the form I'm taking the values from all the checkboxes and passing that into a script (which I already had) that basically writes a CSV file.

What I do is that upon submitting the form, the CSV file is created in the background and sent back to the user for download immediately. I got this part working by making my script create the file in memory ([using StringIO](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/32/)) and then returning it using Flask's [send_file](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.send_file).

What I would like is to also to give the user some feedback after he downloads the file by flashing a message to the template (you could ask why do I want to notify the user if he already downloaded the file - I just want to give him some extra information). However, after my view function returns send_file and presents a download dialog in the browser, the page isn't reloaded so the flash message doesn't get through.

I'm struggling with this: how can I return the file and also show a message to the user? I understand that each request can only have one response, so if I use my one chance with the file download I might need another strategy. Any ideas?

Here's how my "download route" looks like:

```
@app.route('/process', methods=["POST"])
def process():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # gets all checkbox values
        fields = request.form.getlist("field")

        # generates my csv file
        csv = generate_csv()

        if len(fields) != 0:
            csv = amxml2csv.xml2csv(xml, *fields)
            flash("Extraction succeeded!")
            return send_file(data, attachment_filename="newresults.csv", as_attachment=True)
        else:
            error = "No fields selected!"
    return render_template("index.html", error=error)
```

Comment: Is this "extra information" something related to the file export itself? If not, you could always just bring the user to a "download" screen with the extra information and a link to the view that actually does the file creation.

Comment: Not really, the extra info is just some feedback to tell the user the file creation was successful. I was thinking that maybe the form can be submitted using ajax as well, but I don't have any experience with that.

Comment: @bergonzzi I'd go with the AJAX idea, capturing the click event and firing your own request (with say $.post in JQuery). But you won't be able to redirect after the AJAX is done, you'll have to insert a link.

Comment: If you don't mind using a bit of javascript, you could [try something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47866877/3794038)

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem here. A halfway solution so far I found is to do

> return send_from_directory() and redirect(url_for())

Comment: This way it'll always execute the last command in the return statement, here in your case as mentioned above it'll only redirect but not send the file.

Answer (score 0):

A simple-ish way would be to open two endpoints with the submit data button, one in a new window.

Presumably you are feeding back on the data so you might need some way of caching the data for the server to parse... maybe you could build in a delay for your feedback endpoint, which may make the data available to the session; or allow time for you to retrieve for that endpoint function. then return the feedback.

Comment: I know this is simple, but can you elaborate on "open two endpoints with the submit data button, one in a new window"?