# How to make flask to send a file and then redirect?

Tags: python, pdf, flask

I want my flask app to send a file and then redirect to the home page.

```
def create_pdf(**kwargs):
    page = PdfManager(**kwargs)
    pdf_out = page.create_pdf()
    response = make_response(pdf_out)
    # redirect(url_for('home'))
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=pdf-test.pdf"
    response.mimetype = 'application/pdf'
    return response

app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    create_pdf(foo='bar')
```

This piece of code properly spits out the pdf file on response but I can't make the page to refresh or redirect after downloading the pdf file. I can't use `send_from_directory` method of flask since this pdf file is dynamically generated using `StringIo` , `PdfFileWriter` objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the "/" path return a html response with javascript like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script>
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.location = "/redirect-uri";
        }, 500)
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe width="0" height="0" src="/path-to-pdf.pdf"/>
</body>
</html>
```

If the pdf is dynamically generated, you should also serve the pdf url like

```
@route('/path-to-pdf.pdf')
def pdf_generator():
    return create_pdf()
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly better way might be to let javascript handle submitting the form as well as the redirect:

```
<form name="createPdf">
    <!-- Your fields etc. here -->
    <a href="javascript:submitAndRedirect()">
        <button>Submit</button> <!-- NB do not use type=submit -->
    </a>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitAndRedirect() {
        document.createPdf.submit();
        setTimeout(function() {
            location.href = YOUR_REDIRECT_URL_HERE;
        }, 500);
    }
</script>
```

The redirectUrl could be injected from python if necessary like this:

```
return render_template("create_pdf.html", redirect_url=url_for("whatever"))
```

Then in your javascript:

```
var redirectUrl = '{{ redirect_url }}';
```